# Fabricjs ERROR transform.actionHandler is not a function when use only custom control

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

Let say I have create a circle object and remove all default controls by replacing them with 2 custom controls call "save" and "cancel". When I clicked on the cancel control sometimes the error `Uncaught TypeError: transform.actionHandler is not a function` appears on console log before arrives to `mouseUpHandler` callback of the custom control as you can see in the screenshot below so how to prevent the error like this?

Here is the example code: https://jsfiddle.net/ckitisak/kzd6Lufa/

Step to reproduce:

1. click on Edit button
2. (optional) Move the object
3. click cancel control (red with x)
4. repeat step 1 - 3 (if error does not appear)

[image]

**UPDATE!**
as Andrea Bogazzi answered on [github issue](https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/issues/6478)

adding noop to actionHandler will solve the problem

```
new fabric.Control({
    ...
    actionHandler: ()=>{}
  });
```

```js
let object
let canvas;
const deleteIcon = "data:image/svg+xml,%3C%3Fxml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'%3F%3E%3C!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd'%3E%3Csvg version='1.1' id='Ebene_1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' x='0px' y='0px' width='595.275px' height='595.275px' viewBox='200 215 230 470' xml:space='preserve'%3E%3Ccircle style='fill:%23F44336;' cx='299.76' cy='439.067' r='218.516'/%3E%3Cg%3E%3Crect x='267.162' y='307.978' transform='matrix(0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 0.7071 -222.6202 340.6915)' style='fill:white;' width='65.545' height='262.18'/%3E%3Crect x='266.988' y='308.153' transform='matrix(0.7071 0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 398.3889 -83.3116)' style='fill:white;' width='65.544' height='262.179'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E";
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = deleteIcon;

const deleteControl = new fabric.Control({
    x: 1,
    y: -1.5,
    offsetY: 16,
    cursorStyle: 'pointer',
    mouseUpHandler: cancel,
    render: renderIcon,
    cornerSize: 24
  });


function initCanvas() {
    canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
    canvas.backgroundColor = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.3)';
    canvas.setHeight(500);
    canvas.setWidth(500);
    canvas.fireRightClick = true;
    canvas.preserveObjectStacking = true;
    canvas.renderOnAddRemove = false;
    canvas.selection = false;
    canvas.stateful = false;
    canvas.stopContextMenu = true;
}

function createObject() {
    object = new fabric.Circle({
        borderColor:'#000',
        cornerColor:'#000',
        cornerSize:10,
        cornerStrokeColor:'#000',
        hasBorders: false,
        hasControls: false,
        objectCaching: false,
        originX: 'center',
        originY: 'center',
        left: 250,
        lockMovementX: true,
        lockMovementY: true,
        lockRotation: true,
        lockScalingX: true,
        lockScalingY: true,
        moveable: false,
        radius: 15,
        selectable: false,
        strokeUniform: true,
        top: 250,
        transparentCorners: false,
    });
    object.controls = { deleteControl };
    canvas.add(object);
    canvas.renderAll();
}

function edit() {
    console.log('edit clicked!')
    
    object.hasBorders = true;
    object.hasControls = true;
    object.lockMovementX = false;
    object.lockMovementY = false;
    object.moveable = true;
    
    canvas.setActiveObject(object);
    canvas.renderAll();
}

function cancel(eventData, target) {
    console.log('cancel clicked!')
    
    createObject();
    
    canvas.remove(target);
    canvas.renderAll();
}

function renderIcon(ctx, left, top, styleOverride, fabricObject) {
    var size = this.cornerSize;
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(left, top);
    ctx.rotate(fabric.util.degreesToRadians(fabricObject.angle));
    ctx.drawImage(img, -size/2, -size/2, size, size);
    ctx.restore();
}

initCanvas();
createObject();
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/fabric@4.0.0-beta.12/dist/fabric.js"></script>

<button type="button" onclick="edit()">Edit</button>

<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

Referenced from https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/issues/6478

Adding  actionHandler: ()=>{}  solved my problem as below.

const deleteControl = new fabric.Control({
x: 1,
y: -1.5,
offsetY: 16,
cursorStyle: 'pointer',
mouseUpHandler: cancel,
render: renderIcon,
cornerSize: 24,
actionHandler: ()=>{}  // This line will solve your problem
});

Comment: Tried in your JsFiddle too.  Let us all know if it solved your problem